# case when in sqlserver

Tags: sql-server, case-when

i try to use case in for my condition to show out which is late,but after i use case when my result show out too many result.

```
select
        grp.checktime,
        --min(CONVERT(smalldatetime,l.checktime)) as clockin,
        --max(CONVERT(smalldatetime,l.checktime)) as clockout,
        ClockIn = case when min(cast(l.checktime as time)) <= cast(sc.StartTime as time)
                        then convert(varchar(100), cast(l.checktime as time), 100)
                        else 'Late ClockIn ' + convert(varchar(100), cast(l.checktime as time), 100)
                        end,
        Clockout = case when max(cast(l.checktime as time)) >= cast(sc.EndTime as time)
                        then convert(varchar(100), cast(l.checktime as time), 100)
                        else 'Early ClockOut ' + convert(varchar(100), cast(l.checktime as time), 100)
                        end,
        l.userid,
        u.showname,
        u.BADGENUMBER
    from checkinout l
    inner join userinfo u on l.userid = u.userid
    inner join UserUsedsclasses uuc on u.userid = uuc.userid
    inner join SchClass sc on uuc.SchId = sc.schClassid
    inner join (
                    select distinct CONVERT(Date,checktime) as checktime
                    from checkinout
                    group by CONVERT(Date,checktime)
                ) as grp on grp.checktime = CONVERT(Date, l.checktime)
    where uuc.SchId = 1 and u.badgenumber = 107
    and u.badgenumber not in (79, 103, 78)
    and l.checktime >= dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, GETDATE() )  , 0)
    and l.checktime <  dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, GETDATE ())+1, 0)
    group by grp.checktime,l.userid,u.showname,u.BADGENUMBER,sc.StartTime,l.checktime,sc.EndTime
```

my result show me 
[image]

Comment: What does `checkinout` look like?  I'm wondering if this a good use case for `LEAD()` or `LAG()`.

Comment: checkinout  is a table name

Comment: Clearly it's a table name.  I'm wondering what the table looks like as in sample data.  Knowing just the query and partial output isn't really informative.

Comment: is record every time punch card time and date

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 0):

Change your `group by` to group by the `date` of `l.checktime`.

```
select
        grp.checktime,
        --min(convert(smalldatetime,l.checktime)) as clockin,
        --max(convert(smalldatetime,l.checktime)) as clockout,
        ClockIn = case when min(cast(l.checktime as time)) <= cast(sc.StartTime as time)
                        then convert(varchar(100), cast(l.checktime as time), 100)
                        else 'Late ClockIn ' + convert(varchar(100), cast(l.checktime as time), 100)
                        end,
        Clockout = case when max(cast(l.checktime as time)) >= cast(sc.EndTime as time)
                        then convert(varchar(100), cast(l.checktime as time), 100)
                        else 'Early ClockOut ' + convert(varchar(100), cast(l.checktime as time), 100)
                        end,
        l.userid,
        u.showname,
        u.BADGENUMBER
    from checkinout l
    inner join userinfo u on l.userid = u.userid
    inner join UserUsedsclasses uuc on u.userid = uuc.userid
    inner join SchClass sc on uuc.SchId = sc.schClassid
    inner join (
                    select distinct convert(Date,checktime) as checktime
                    from checkinout
                    group by convert(Date,checktime)
                ) as grp on grp.checktime = convert(Date, l.checktime)
    where uuc.SchId = 1 and u.badgenumber = 107
      and u.badgenumber not in (79, 103, 78)
      and l.checktime >= dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, getdate() )  , 0)
      and l.checktime <  dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, getdate ())+1, 0)
    group by 
        grp.checktime
      , l.userid
      , u.showname
      , u.BADGENUMBER
      , sc.StartTime
      , convert(date, l.checktime)
      , sc.EndTime
```